# how to access a multilevel key/value from an object within another object

Tags: javascript, object, key

So for instance if I the following two objects

```
var person = {};

person.name = 'Austin';

person.personality = 'Awsome';

var job = {};

job.title = 'space cowboy';

job.pay = 10,000;

person.job = job;
```

and I want to programmatically list each key and value par in a for loop I have the following

```
for(var key in person){
console.log(key)
console.log(person.key)
}
```

How would I be able to detect in this loop when key reaches job without hardcoding `if person.key == job`. Also how would i list out all of jobs keys from within this for loop?

Comment: so you are just wanting to print a recursive list of K->V pairs?

Comment: Ya for this simple example. I'm having trouble figuring out how to set up the second level of this for loop.

Comment: to put in a flag, you will need more lines of code.....  an if statement or some sort of (A==B)?C:D statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function trace(ob){
    for (var item in ob){
        if (typeof ob[item] == 'object') trace(ob[item]);

        console.log("key", item);
        console.log("value", ob[item]);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this what you were thinking of?

Comment: Ya sorry about the delayed response. For about the concept of recursion for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You could obviously do a lot about the formatting, but here's a simple example of walking through the object recursively.  Maybe it'll help show you what you need to do:

```
function iterate(object) {
  for(var key in object) {
    if (object[key] instanceof Object) {
      iterate(object[key]);
    }
    else {
      console.log(key + ": " + object[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's an example if it helps: http://jsbin.com/AmUkIPO/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could this instead:

*how would i list out all of jobs keys*

```
var keys = Object.keys(person.job); // get the all the properties keys as array.

keys.map(function(prop, index){
    //prop is a propery 
    // index: the index position in the array
     // prop === "property named"
});
```

How to get the values and compared them:

```
for (prop in person) {
   if (person[prop] === someValue){
      ..
   }
 }
```

*someValue: means a value in case you want to search for something else other than just getting the value type.

All together:

```
for (prop in person) {
       if (person[prop] === someValue){
         var keys = Object.keys(person[prop]); // get the all the properties keys as array.
       }
     }
```